# linear operator on normed spaces

Tags: operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let $V$ and $W$, normed spaces and $T:V \to W$ a linear operator. How to prove that: "if $T$ is continuous in $0$, so, $\forall A \subset V$ bounded, $T(A)$ is also bounded"

Comment: There exists $\delta>0$ so $||Tx||\le1$ for every $x$ with $||x||<\delta$. Linearity shows that $||Tx||\le||x||/\delta$ for every $x$...

Comment: ok, but the fact that $A$ is bounded, where do you use it?

Comment: I use that in the rest of the solution! What I wrote was a hint. A _big_ hint. Think about it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classically, the approach is to show that $T(B_V)$, where $B_V$ is the unit ball of $V$, is bounded in $W$. That is, $T(B_V) \subseteq MB_W$ for some $M$. Then, if we have any bounded set $A$, that is $A \subseteq NB_V$, then,
$$T(A) \subseteq T(NB_V) = NT(B_V) \subseteq NM B_W,$$
i.e. $T(A)$ is bounded, which is what we want to prove.

So, by continuity at $0$, there must exist some $\delta > 0$ such that,
$$0 < \|x - 0\| < \delta \implies \|T(x) - T(0)\| < 1.$$
Therefore, if $\|x\| \le 1$, then $\|x\| < 2$, hence $\|\delta x / 2\| < \delta$, so $\delta \|T(x)\|/2 = \|T(\delta x/2)\| < 1$. That is,
$$\|x\| \le 1 \implies \|T(x)\| \le 2 / \delta.$$
If we let $M = 2 / \delta$, then we have $T(B_V) \subseteq MB_W$, as required.

Comment: thank you, but i don't understand what is "$ MB_W$ for some $M$"?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I assumed this was common notation. What I mean by $MB_W$ is the set $\lbrace Mx : x \in B_W\rbrace = \lbrace x \in W : \|x\| \le M \rbrace$. It's the ball of radius $M$, which is just the scaling of the unit ball by $M$.

Comment: $B_V=\lbrace x \in V : \|x-0\| < 1 \rbrace$?

Comment: why does $T(NB_V) = NT(B_V)$  is true?

Comment: From the linearity of $T$. If $x \in T(NB_V)$, then $x = T(Ny)$ for some $y \in B_V$  (i.e. $\|y\| \le 1$). But then $x = NT(y)$. Since $y \in B_V$, we have $T(y) \in T(B_V)$, and $x = NT(y) \in NT(B_V)$. The other set inclusion follows similarly.

Answer (score 1):

Let $r>$ be such that: $ A \subset B_r(0)  $. With $B_r(0)$ the ball of radius $r$ centered in $0$. 
Suppose $T(A)$ is not bounded. Then for each $n \in N$ there exists a $x_n \in A$ such that: $||Tx_n|| > n+1 $. 
The sequence $\frac{x_n}{n+1}$ converges to $0$ because $A$ is bounded.
But clearly $|| T \left( \frac{x_n}{n+1} \right)|| >1$. This contradicts continuity in $0$, because the sequence $T \left( \frac{x_n}{n+1} \right)$ doesn't converge to $T(0) = 0$.

Comment: You need "norm signs" right after "But clearly"; otherwise very clear and concise.

Comment: Totaly true, edited it.